# Linux: Allow/restrict IP bind permissions by user

Tags: linux, ip

I'm running a dedicated machine on RHEL (CentOS 6.3) that runs with multiple IP addresses. Multiple users also have access to the machine, on non-superuser accounts. I would like to prevent them from binding to certain addresses.

I do know that Linux can restrict ports for non-root users, as is currently done for ports smaller than or equal to 1024. If I wanted to prevent access to a specific IP address such as `0.0.0.0`, or a range such as `127.0.0.0/8`, would doing so be possible, and if so, how would it be done?

Or inversely, how would I deny all access to bind to any IP addresses, and grant access to individual addresses by user?

Comment: SELinux would be an option

Comment: But sadly, SELinux sucks. Network namespaces provide a mechanism for seperatining access to specific interfaces and with with iptables, routing, bridging and dummy interface, you have a set of primitives from which it is possible to implement complex security policies - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210982/bind-unix-program-to-specific-network-interface

Answer (score 2):

I won't go into detail on how SELinux is set up or how one creates a SELinux policy. [This](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/opensource/practical-selinux-for-the-beginner-contexts-and-labels/2458) might be a good starting point for getting familiar with SELinux.

To address your problem with SELinux, try this:

- Assign a type to the network interface you like to restrict

  ```
  # Assign a type to the whole interface
  semanage interface -a -t foo_netif_t eth2
  ```
- Assign labels to traffic passing through the interface

  ```
  netlabelctl unlbl add interface:eth2 address:0.0.0.0/0 label:system_u:object_r:foo_peer_t:s0
  netlabelctl unlbl add interface:eth2 address:::/0 label:system_u:object_r:foo_peer_t:s0
  ```

  This example assigns the type `foo_peer_t` to all IPv4 and IPv6 traffic.
- Add rules to allow packet flow

  Traffic entering

  ```
  allow user_t foo_netif_t:netif ingress;
  allow user_t foo_peer_t:node recvfrom;
  ```

  Traffic leaving

  ```
  allow user_t foo_netif_t:netif egress;
  allow user_t foo_peer_t:node sendto;
  ```

  Replace `user_t` with type assigned to the user you wish to restrict.

References:

- [Labeling interfaces](http://paulmoore.livejournal.com/5536.html?nojs=1)
- [Ingress/Egress controls](http://paulmoore.livejournal.com/2128.html?nojs=1)